# Azure Python SDK- Spinup VM with cloud-init

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, virtual-machine, azure-sdk

I'm trying to spin up VM with cloud-init using Azure SDK.
Script is based on this example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/blob/master/example.py I have added following:

`with open(cloudinit, "r") as cl:
    clcont=cl.read()
    # CUSTOM_DATA=base64.b64encode(clcont.encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
    CUSTOM_DATA=clcont`

Next in the function `create_vm_parameters` added:
`'custom-data': CUSTOM_DATA`

I have tried following examples:

- passed base64, base64 ascii decoded as well as plain script context.
- provide `custom-data` in `os_profile` as well as separated block.

When trying to spin up vm with `az cli`, the cloud-init script works fine. 
Do you have any ideas how to make it work with python sdk? Perhaps I am adding it in the incorrect section while creating the vm parameters?

Comment: Where do you add the custom-data? Is it in the os_profile?

Comment: I tried both: in os_profile and on the same level. both didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one has answer, my colleague solved it.

Saved cloudinit as yaml file, and:

`clcont== '\n'.join([
        '', yaml.dump(cloudinit), ])
   CUSTOM_DATA = base64.b64encode(clcont.encode('utf-8')).decode('latin-1')`

And put it in `os_profile`: `'custom_data': CUSTOM_DATA,`