# How to Specify Cloud-Init When Creating A Virtual Machine with the Azure Python Compute SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk

I am looking to run a startup script on a linux virtual machine when I create and start it with the Azure Python SDK. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `cloud-init` as the value of the `custom_data` in the VM [os_profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.osprofile?view=azure-python). But as the property shows:

> Specifies a base-64 encoded string of custom data. The base-64 encoded
>   string is decoded to a binary array that is saved as a file on the
>   Virtual Machine. The maximum length of the binary array is 65535
>   bytes.

Its value should be a base-64 encoded string. You can how to do it from another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856792/azure-python-sdk-spinup-vm-with-cloud-init).